# Passing validation DTO as generic to a parent class. Nest.js

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator

I have a base class CRUD implementation that looks like this:

```
abstract class BaseController<T extends BaseEntity, E> {
 constructor(private readonly IBaseService: IBaseService<T, E>) {}

 @Post()
 @ApiResponse({
   status: 201,
   description: 'The record has been successfully created.',
 })
 @ApiResponse({ status: 403, description: 'Forbidden.' })
 @ApiResponse({ status: 400, description: 'Bad Request.' })
 @SetMetadata('code', `WRITE`)
 async create(@Body() entity: E): Promise<E> {
   return this.IBaseService.create(entity)
 }
}
```

and a class of the provider controller that extends the base class for CRUD methods:

```
@ApiTags('providers')
@Controller('providers')
@SetMetadata('code', 'PROVIDER')
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
export class ProviderController extends BaseController<Providers, ProviderDto> {
  constructor(private readonly providersService: ProvidersService) {
    super(providersService)
  }
}
```

I need to pass the ProviderDto to the parent class BaseController to validate the `create` method with `ValidationPipe`.
But for some reason it doesn't work this way. Maybe my approach is incorrect?